# Elasticsearch: How insert nested Json array object into Elasticsearch Index

Tags: elasticsearch

How to insert the following JSON nested array abject into Elasticsearch index named `"index_19_7_16"`?

```
{
      "hour": [
        {
          "time": "00:00",
          "master_id": [
            {
              "m.id": 111,
              "m.value": 222
            },
            {
              "m.id": 113,
              "m.value": 444
            }
          ],
          "child_id": [
            {
              "c.id": 77,
              "c.value": 222
            },
            {
              "c.id": 7751,
              "c.value": 444
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "time": "01:00",
          "master_id": [
            {
              "m.id": 111,
              "m.value": 222
            },
            {
              "m.id": 113,
              "m.value": 444
            }
          ],
          "child_id": [
            {
              "c.id": 77,
              "c.value": 222
            },
            {
              "c.id": 7751,
              "c.value": 444
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Do I need to created mapping before or just insert the JSON dynamically into elastic index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create the mapping upfront and specifically mention that some fields have to be `"type":"nested"` otherwise ES will just create objects. Here I specifically refer to [nested type of fields in ES](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/nested.html#_using_literal_nested_literal_fields_for_arrays_of_objects).

If by *nested* you meant just the nested nature of the document, then you don't have to do anything.

Comment: Andrei Stefan: Thanks, and what way is better for searching/aggregations issues , either create "type":"nested" or just insert the Json without any mapping?

Comment: The `nested` story is about associating a field value with another field value from the same `nested` field. In your case, if your future queries care about `"m.id": 111` to be considered as "connected" with `"m.value": 222` then you need `nested`.

Comment: My future aggregation would be sum all  "m.id": 111, values between ranges  of hours.. For instance:  SUM+= between 00:00-02:00 all values from  "m.id": 111

Comment: Please, read the docs link I provided in the answer. The example there is relevant: first name and last name. Obviously, each person has one of those. With nested fields a certain first name belongs to a certain last name. With non-nested fields that association is lost. This is all about with nested fields.